# RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, cudnn

I am running CNN algorithm using PyTorch on my new machine with 3 Nvidia GPUs and getting the error below:

```
RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED

File "code.py", line 342, in <module>
    trainer.fit(model)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 514, in fit
    self.dispatch()

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 554, in dispatch
    self.accelerator.start_training(self)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 74, in start_training
    self.training_type_plugin.start_training(trainer)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py", line 111, in start_training
    self._results = trainer.run_train()

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 615, in run_train
    self.run_sanity_check(self.lightning_module)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 864, in run_sanity_check
    _, eval_results = self.run_evaluation(max_batches=self.num_sanity_val_batches)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 733, in run_evaluation
    output = self.evaluation_loop.evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/evaluation_loop.py", line 164, in evaluation_step
    output = self.trainer.accelerator.validation_step(args)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 178, in validation_step
    return self.training_type_plugin.validation_step(*args)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/ddp.py", line 290, in validation_step
    return self.model(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 705, in forward
    output = self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/overrides/base.py", line 63, in forward
    output = self.module.validation_step(*inputs, **kwargs)

  File code.py", line 314, in validation_step
    pred = self.forward(x)

  File code.py", line 259, in forward
    x = self.conv0(x)          #([12, 600, 600])

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 119, in forward
    input = module(input)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 399, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)

  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 395, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,



NVIDIA-MSI:
```

[image]

The code is running without any issue on another machine with driver version 450.51.06 and Cuda version 11. You can see nvidia-smi of new machine above. I checked different comments on other questions same to this issue and non of them resolved my issue.